# Expose feed file in /pub

Tags: magento2.2.6, nginx

I dare say this is a newbie question but I've not found anyone else asking it.

I am going through a steep learning curve having just taken over a site running **magento 2.2.6** on **magestack** on **nginx** (none of which I know!).

There is an **extension** which is creating a google shopping feed in  `/pub/feeds/` but although I can download it over ftp, the feed file returns a **404** to a browser so I infer that google won't be able to pull it.

I already hit the same issue trying to verify the site with the google merchant account by uploading a file to the root (which also returned a 404) but I was able to work around that with a tag instead.

**nginx** doesn't have **htaccess** files and if it were something every magento operator had to do I think my searching would have turned something up by now, so any pointers to what's going on would be appreciated.

Edit: having set up a fresh install I see that it's not default magento behaviour.

#### Further Info:

**nginx configuration** can include **location rules** to **route** urls to paths. In this case the magento root is the domain root and the configuration routes requests to eg.
`domain.com/media/catalog/product/1/1/image.jpg` to the path
`/var/usr/domain/html/pub/media/catalog/product/1/1/image.jpg`.
It's set up so that any routes without a matching rule return a **404**
so that a further location rule would be needed to route requests to pub

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is determine which directory Magento is using for web root - for example if your Magento rood directory is `/usr/share/nginx/html`, then either `/usr/share/nginx/html` ***or*** `/usr/share/nginx/html/pub` might be set as root. Once you sort that out the path for access from the browser should be clear (i.e. something.com/pub/something-in-pub or something.com/something-in-pub).

After that, if you aren't able to reach files I would look at their permissions and possibly nginx rewrite config.

You've probably seen these, but just in case :

[Info on Magento 2 docroot](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html)

[Info on Magento & Nginx](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/nginx.html)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I already tried example.com/feeds/google.xml as well as example.com/pub/feeds/google.xml and they both give 404 so I'm digging into .conf files and trying to figure the path to nginx.

Comment: [This comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/363371/116707) might be helpful. If there are docs for the extension generating the feed you might see if they had recommended config.